# Keyword can't be expression - View

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to create database with Django and fill it ower URL but I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\Final\vj_2\vj_2\app_1\views.py", line 12
    'naslov'=naslov,
    ^ SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

I don't know what am I missing here and why it doesn't work.

This is my view:

```
def dodajClanak(request, naslov, datumObjave, autor):
    clan = Clanak(
        'naslov'=naslov,
        'datumObjave'=datumObjave,
        'autor'=autor
        )
    clan.save()#ako podaci nisu dobri throwat ce error
    return render(request, 'allapp.html', {'data': naslov + ' ' + datumObjave + ' ' + autor})
```

And my model:

```
class Clanak(models.Model):
    naslov = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=120)
    #naslov = models.DecimalField(null=False, blank=False, decimal_places=1, max_digits=5)
    datumObjave = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    autor = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.naslov) + ', ' + str(self.datumObjave) + ', ' + str(self.autor)
```

Full error log:

> Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "c:\users\%username%\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\threading.py",
>   line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "c:\users\%username%\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\threading.py",
>   line 865, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
>   line 54, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 117, in inner_run
>       self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 390, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 377, in _run_checks
>       return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",
>   line 72, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 13, in check_url_config
>       return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 23, in check_resolver
>       return check_method()   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line
>   398, in check
>       for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 80, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line
>   579, in url_patterns
>       patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
>   "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 80, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line
>   572, in urlconf_module
>       return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "C:\Final\vj_2\venv\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in
>   import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 983, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 728, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Final\vj_2\vj_2\vj_2\urls.py", line 18, in 
>       from app_1 import views   File "C:\Final\vj_2\vj_2\app_1\views.py", line 12
>       'naslov'=naslov,
>       ^ SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from app_1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', views.home),
    re_path('add/(?P<naslov>[a-zA-Z]+/(?P<datumObjave>[0-9]+)/(?P<autor>[a-zA-Z]+', views.dodajClanak),
]
```

Comment: `'datum_objave'` --> `datumObjave` ?

Comment: @Rakesh I fixed that, but still same error on "Naslov"

Comment: Can you post your full error?

Comment: @Rakesh I posted full error log

Comment: @justStarting show your url code

Comment: @c.grey I added url code, I am not sure for parameter datumObjave as it should be date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following code:

```
# views.py
def dodajClanak(request, naslov, datumObjave, autor):
    Clanak.objects.create(
        naslov=naslov,
        datumObjave=datumObjave,
        autor=autor
    )
    return render(request, 'allapp.html', {'data': f'{naslov} {datumObjave} {autor}'})

# urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from app_1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', views.home),
    re_path('add/(?P<naslov>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?P<datumObjave>[-/0-9]+)/(?P<autor>[a-zA-Z]+)/', views.dodajClanak),
]
```

Comment: It works, well at least server is running, I have to test insert into database now. Can You tell me what we do here? Thank You. Do You know with what should I replace "(?P<datumObjave>[-/0-9]+)" for date format?

Comment: datumObjave can be '2019-05-21' or '2019/05/21'

Comment: Now I am getting: "no such table: app_1_clanak" error

Comment: Maybe you should run `python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate` at first.

Answer (score 1):

```
def dodajClanak(request, naslov, datumObjave, autor):
clan = Clanak(
    'naslov':naslov,
    'datumObjave':datumObjave,
    'autor':autor
    )
clan.save()#ako podaci nisu dobri throwat ce error
context ={
    data:"naslov + ' ' + datumObjave + ' ' + autor"
}
return render(request, 'allapp.html', context)
```

'datum_objave'==>datumObjave

Comment: I fixed that already by @Rakesh suggestion but error was still the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dodajClanak(request, naslov, datumObjave, autor):
    clan = Clanak(
        'naslov':naslov,
        'datum_objave':datumObjave,
        'autor':autor
        )
    clan.save()#ako podaci nisu dobri throwat ce error
    return render(request, 'allapp.html', {'data': naslov + ' ' + datumObjave + ' ' + autor})
```